# Discrepancy in Post Counts between Local MySQL Stack Overflow Database and Data Stack Exchange Query

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, data-explorer, data-dump

I recently downloaded the Stack Overflow data from [Stack Overflow datadump](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange) and imported it into my local MySQL database. While attempting to retrieve the total number of posts for the year 2021 using the query below, I encountered differing results compared to querying the live database on **data.stackexchange.com**.

Query used:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id) AS NumberOfPosts2021
FROM posts
WHERE YEAR(CreationDate) = 2021;
```

The local database query returned a count of "3550674," while the live database query produced a count of "3549232."

I'm concerned that there might be some data loss during the import process. Could anyone provide insights into why there is a difference between the two values? Additionally, is there a way to verify whether I've imported the data correctly into my MySQL database? Any assistance or guidance on how to troubleshoot this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Additionally, is there a way to verify whether I've imported the data correctly into my MySQL database?" That's out of scope of MSE AFAIK.

Comment: Posts could have been automatically deleted or otherwise removed between 2021 and now?

Comment: That's a difference of 1,442 posts. That seems within the realm of reasonable to me (i.e. it's not enough to trigger my "something's wrong" warning). The live database will continue to have had posts deleted in the time between the data dump snapshot and the current SEDE snapshot. Probably the most significant of those would be posts newly qualifying for [the Roomba](/help/auto-deleted-questions). There's not a huge difference, because you're looking at posts outside the 30 and 365 day watersheds, but there's also other criteria, including views/time, which can easily kick in.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at posts with deleted to see if those numbers matched. You could, if you want, even list, or just get the quantity of, the posts that were deleted in the time between the snapshots.

Comment: ^ to clarify, the table `PostsWithDeleted`. It includes a `DeletionDate` to indicate posts that may have been deleted between the data dump (June 5th) and the last data explorer refresh (August 6th). And/or if you find a PostId that is in your database but not in Data Explorer, post it here, that might help us find out what's different about that post.

Comment: I'd also check if there are any duplicate Ids in your local copy. I'm not familiar with MySQL's import process but if it's anything like their GROUP BY, I don't know how much I would trust it.

Comment: Thanks for response @Makyen - However, I've noticed that my local MySQL database contains fewer posts than the live Stack Exchange database. If posts were deleted after the most recent data dump, one might expect my database to have more posts than the live database. This seems contradictory, as deletions would typically reduce the count of posts.

Comment: The numbers you specified in the question here show a larger number for posts in your "local database", which is, presumably, the data dump in your MySQL instance and 1,442 fewer in the "live database query", which is, presumably, the current SEDE. That's as expected, assuming some posts have been deleted between the data dump and the current SEDE.

Comment: A bit more on the matching of the number of deleted posts, even the number of undeleted posts will matter (Post might not be in the data dump due to it being deleted at that point but be in SEDE due to being undeleted). Also getting the correct number for that might still be difficult since the exact timestamp of when the dump started might not be known by the community.

Answer (score 6):

There will always be discrepancies between the count of rows in the datadump and SEDE. The chance they are both based on the same data is near zero.

Even the weekly refreshed SEDE database will be inconsistent in some cases as data is copied from the live database, there is no snapshot taken.

As explained in the comments, posts get deleted regularly, either on a schedule, due to moderation or by the Original Poster.

We're talking about a difference of 1,442 posts. This would mean that since June 13th (the date the latest datadump was published) and last Sunday (the most recent SEDE refresh) around 1,442 posts that were created in 2021 are now deleted.

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1774505) should give us that ballpark figure:

```
select count(*) [deleted 2021 since June 13th] 
from postswithdeleted
where year(creationdate) = 2021
and deletiondate > '2023-06-13'
```

That returns today 1,339 posts that might still be in your datadump but won't be in the next datadump because today those are deleted.

On the other hand 69 post from 2021 got undeleted after June, 13th:

```
select count(distinct p.id) [undeleted 2021 since June 13th] 
from posts p
inner join posthistory ph on ph.postid = p.id
where year(p.creationdate) = 2021
and ph.creationdate > '2023-06-13'
and ph.posthistorytypeid = 13 -- undelete event
```

I don't think there is data loss in the datadump you have. The differences you see are explainable, backed by data evidence from SEDE.

Comment: Agreed, probably any discrepancy can be explained by these factors. If there is a specific PostId that is present in one source but not the other, and can't be explained by any of the above, give me the ID and I'll try to explain it. If I can't, I'd suggest that it is a side effect of the import process into MySQL, which we'd have a hard time reproducing.